# Importing CSV via ORACLE SQL LOADER, line break in double-quote

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm trying to import CSV via Oracle `SQL*LOADER`, but I have a problem because some data has line break within the double-quotes.  For example

"text.csv"

```
John,123,New York
Tom,456,Paris
Park,789,"Europe
London, City"
```

I think that `SQL*LOADER` uses the line break character to separate records.
This data generates an error "second enclosure string not present"

I use this control file.
(control.txt)

```
OPTIONS(LOAD=-1, ERRORS=-1)
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'test.csv'
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE TMP
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(
 field1,
 field2,
 field3
)
```

and I execute a command like this

```
sqlldr 'scott/tiger' control='control.txt' log='result.txt'
```

I want to import 3 records, not 4 records...
can `SQL*LOADER` ignore line breaks within double-quotes?

Answer (score 2):

Seems you need to get rid of *carriage return* and/or *line feed* characters.

So replace

`field3`
with

```js
field3 CHAR(4000) "REPLACE(TRIM(:field3),CHR(13)||CHR(10))"'
```

or

```js
field3 CHAR(4000) "REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(:field3),CHR(13)),CHR(10))"'
```

where using a `TRIM()` would be useful in order to remove trailing and leading *whitespaces*.

Answer (score 1):

In case you would like to preserve the embedded carriage returns, construct the control file like this using the "str" (stream) clause on the infile option line to set the end of record character. It tells sqlldr that hex 0D (carriage return, or ^M) is the record separator (this way it will ignore the linefeeds inside the double-quotes):

```
INFILE 'test.csv' "str x'0D'"
```